# The Delay property of a toast in Jquery, does not work on a site built in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a mysql database connection built with PHP. At the frontend level I have included Bootstrap and Jquery, to be able to include toasts among many things. These notifications are shown after entering the data to the database, but the time in which they are visible is very short, not being able to modify the time with delay.

I already tried including the toast script inside the body and the head of the form, as in an external file called with defer, so as not to cause conflicts in the order of loading scripts, but still I cannot modify the toast delay.
I am working on a local installation with Debian.

I. The toast code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnEnter").click(function(){
     $("#enter_data").toast({ delay: 5000 });
     $('#enter_data').toast('show');
     });
});
```

II. Part of the form code (currently invoking it from an external file // with defer):

```
<input id="btnEnter" type="submit" name="enter_data" value="Enter Card" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>

</div>



<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="min-height: 200px;">

  <!-- Then put toasts within -->
  <div class="toast" id="enter_data" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
```

I do not understand why if the toast is displayed correctly, its delay property does not work correctly.

Comment: What toast plugin are you using? The jquery toast plugin [here](https://kamranahmed.info/toast) does not pass an element at all, so I'm confused and how this should work.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap Toasts: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/ (I'm using Bootstrap in my form).

Comment: I'm going to try the api you sent.

Comment: Why not just put it in via HTML attributes: ie. `data-delay="500"`?

Comment: The toast plugin you sent me works for me! Thanks  FrankerZ !

Answer (score 1):

Adding the data-delay attribute to the tag works for me as described by [ugh StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4875631/ugh-stackexchange).

Please try the below code

HTML:

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative; z-index:9999; top: 15px;">
    <!-- Position it -->
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0;">

        <!-- Then put toasts within -->
        <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="2000">
            <div class="toast-header">
                <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
                <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
                <small class="text-muted">just now</small>
                <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="toast-body">
                See? Just like this.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="4000">
            <div class="toast-header">
                <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
                <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
                <small class="text-muted">2 seconds ago</small>
                <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="toast-body">
                Heads up, toasts will stack automatically
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".toast").each(function (index, e) {
  $(e).toast("show");
})
```